# How to connect PrintDocument_PrintPage code to button in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**My code for PrintDocument_PrintPage is the following:**

```cs
 private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //sets up printing

            Font PrintFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
            Font HeadingFont = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
            int CountInteger;
            string PrintLineString;
            Single PrintYSingle = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            Single PrintXSingle = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            Single LineHeightSingle = PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + 2;

            //sets up printing
            PrintLineString = "Employee Records";
            e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, HeadingFont, Brushes.BlueViolet, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);

            PrintYSingle += LineHeightSingle * 2;
            PrintLineString = "IdNo";
            e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, HeadingFont, Brushes.BlueViolet, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);

            PrintXSingle += 75;
            PrintLineString = "Name";
            e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, HeadingFont, Brushes.BlueViolet, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);

            PrintXSingle += 105;
            PrintLineString = "Dept";
            e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, HeadingFont, Brushes.BlueViolet, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);

            PrintXSingle = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            PrintYSingle += LineHeightSingle * 2;
            this.employeesBindingSource.MoveFirst();

            for (CountInteger = 0; CountInteger < this.employeesBindingSource.Count; CountInteger++) ;
            {
                PrintLineString = this.emp_IDTextBox.Text;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, PrintFont, Brushes.DarkGreen, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);

                PrintXSingle += 75;
                PrintLineString = this.emp_NameTextBox.Text;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, PrintFont, Brushes.DarkOrange, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);
                
                PrintXSingle += 150;
                PrintLineString = this.deptTextBox.Text;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintLineString, PrintFont, Brushes.DarkRed, PrintXSingle, PrintYSingle);

                PrintXSingle = e.MarginBounds.Left;
                PrintYSingle += LineHeightSingle;
                this.employeesBindingSource.MoveNext();
            }
```

**However, when I click on the button (private void PreviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)), it doesn't seem to find the code and open it. What am I missing?** Am I supposed to add more details or code in the actual button? Still learning how to use visualstudio

Comment: What are the codes in `PreviewButton_Click(...)`?

Comment: You need to call `Print` on your `PrintDocument` in order to initiate the printing process. Are you doing that in the `Click` event handler that you haven't shown us? Also, if you have copied and pasted that code form the web then it won't be automatically registered to handle the `PrintPage` event of your `PrintDocument`, so make sure that is done.

Comment: By the way, it's not great that you are actually navigating in the UI and getting data from controls during the print process. I would suggest that you should be looping over the `BindingSource` itself and getting the data from its items. You should also be aware that, if your list is long enough, you'll actually print off the end of the page. If that's a potential issue then you need to account for that and print multiple pages.